# Page not working properly on jquery load function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#send").click(function(){
      $("#image_results").load('/gallary1.php');
   });
});
</script>
```

When I click the send button it should load gallary1.php into the image_results `<Div>` however it doesn't load it properly?

If I just use the include_once("gallary1.php"); command inside the `<Div>` then is displays properly. I'm guessing the Script is changing the code somehow but have no idea how.

Below is the php page I'm trying to load in.

```
$gallary="";
$gallary.='


<div class="content">
                <div id="rg-gallery" class="rg-gallery">
                    <div class="rg-thumbs">

                        <div class="es-carousel-wrapper">
                            <div class="es-nav">
                                <span class="es-nav-prev">Previous</span>
                                <span class="es-nav-next">Next</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="es-carousel">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-large="images/1.jpg" alt="image01" data-description="From off a hill whose concave womb reworded" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" data-large="images/2.jpg" alt="image02" data-description="A plaintful story from a sistering vale" /></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';


echo $gallary;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also if there is any more info I need to provide please let me know.

I have found that if I load gallary1.php via include then the resulting html is:

```
<div class="content">
                <div id="rg-gallery" class="rg-gallery"><div class="rg-view"><a href="#" class="rg-view-full"></a><a href="#" class="rg-view-thumbs rg-view-selected"></a></div>
                    <div class="rg-thumbs">

                        <div class="es-carousel-wrapper">
                            <div class="es-nav">
                                <span class="es-nav-prev">Previous</span>
                                <span class="es-nav-next">Next</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="es-carousel">
                                <ul style="width: 154px; display: block; margin-left: 0px;">
                                    <li class="selected" style="margin-right: 3px; width: 69px;"><a href="#" style="border-width: 2px;"><img src="http://www.fyom.16mb.com/images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-large="images/1.jpg" alt="image01" data-description="From off a hill whose concave womb reworded"></a></li>
                                    <li style="margin-right: 3px; width: 69px;"><a href="#" style="border-width: 2px;"><img src="http://www.fyom.16mb.com/images/thumbs/2.jpg" data-large="images/2.jpg" alt="image02" data-description="A plaintful story from a sistering vale"></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        <div class="es-nav"><span class="es-nav-prev" style="display: none;">Previous</span><span class="es-nav-next" style="display: none;">Next</span></div></div>

                    </div>
                <div class="rg-image-wrapper">           <div class="rg-image-nav">       <a href="#" class="rg-image-nav-prev">Previous Image</a>       <a href="#" class="rg-image-nav-next">Next Image</a>      </div>          <div class="rg-image"><img src="images/1.jpg"></div>     <div class="rg-loading" style="display: none;"></div>     <div class="rg-caption-wrapper">      <div class="rg-caption" style="">       <p>From off a hill whose concave womb reworded</p>      </div>     </div>    </div></div>
        </div>
```

However when is loaded via the script:

```
<div class="content">
                <div id="rg-gallery" class="rg-gallery">
                    <div class="rg-thumbs">

                        <div class="es-carousel-wrapper">
                            <div class="es-nav">
                            <span class="es-nav-prev">Previous</span>
                            <span class="es-nav-next">Next</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="es-carousel">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-large="images/1.jpg" alt="image01" data-description="From off a hill whose concave womb reworded"></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" data-large="images/2.jpg" alt="image02" data-description="A plaintful story from a sistering vale"></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So something is not being picked up. As is it displaying what I echo out however when the page loaded properly is is inheriting additional formatting.

Comment: provides more information. What's displayed on your browser console? What's your folder structure?

Comment: define *"doesn't load properly"*

Comment: Why use `php`? You could create `.html` document containing `html` content `echo`ed from `php`

Comment: I have now included the htlml that is generated when i include the file and when i use the .load option. Does that help?

Comment: Still not clear what problem actually is. do you or do you not get anything populated? If not...then inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for clues..status, what is returned etc

Comment: I am using php as the images will be loaded dynamically once I can get it to display properly.

Comment: I think whole problem is there is a plugin involved that you need to initialize in load callback

Comment: thanks charlietf1 how would I initialise the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute using `.html` for `php`, as no dynamic data appears to be included at `html` `echo`ed from `php`

gallary1.html

```
   <div class="content">
            <div id="rg-gallery" class="rg-gallery">
                <div class="rg-thumbs">

                    <div class="es-carousel-wrapper">
                        <div class="es-nav">
                            <span class="es-nav-prev">Previous</span>
                            <span class="es-nav-next">Next</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="es-carousel">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" data-large="images/1.jpg" alt="image01" data-description="From off a hill whose concave womb reworded" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" data-large="images/2.jpg" alt="image02" data-description="A plaintful story from a sistering vale" /></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#send").click(function(){
      $("#image_results").load("gallary1.html");
   });
});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/VN5KUgrXpZtrkCAKr2I6?p=preview

Comment: Hi sorry there will be dynamic data i just need to get it displaying properly first.

Comment: Are the double quotes within `html` at `php` escaped properly?

Comment: If I use include to insert the file everything works fine. It's only when the script loads the file that it doesn't.

Comment: What does `$.get("/gallary1.php").then(function(data){console.log(data)})` log at `console`? _"I have found that if i load gallary1.php via include then the resulting html is:"_  `html` at expected result  appears to contain an extra closing `<div>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do get html loaded ( still not clear after numerous requests for clarification) ... I believe you have some sort of carousel plugin involved that you need to initialize on the new html in load callback

```
$("#send").click(function(){
      $("#image_results").load("gallary1.html", function(){
           // new html now exists, iniitlaize plugin now
           $(this).myCarouselPlugin();
       });
});
```

Comment: Yes I am using a carousel plugin sorry. When it's included the result is the html show last in the question when via the script I get the second last block in the question. Assuming it is not able to inherit from the carousel plugin

Comment: So my answer will do what is needed then. Note that whole problem description given was very confusing. Would have helped to say that you can see the html and that it was supposed to act as carousel

Comment: Sorry wrong way round. Script is last code block. Include is 2nd from last.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#send").click(function(){
            $.get('/gallary1.php', function(result) {
                $("#image_results").html(result);
            })
        });
    });
</script>`
```

And in your `gallary1.php`:

```
//echo your html here
```

Or the second way:
Your `gallary1.php`:

```
require_once('content.php');
```

then create another php file of content `content.php`:

```
//your html here, don't have to use echo
```

Answer (score -2):

you must see if you call your gallary1.php directly in the browser, it's give you something..

You can look at the chmod ( 755 for example) of this file ..

if your file is in the same folde, you can put:

```
$("#image_results").load('gallary1.php');//without the /
```

Comment: thanks. Yes it is in the same folder. I have now included the htlml that is generated when i include the file and when i use the .load option.